# Как удалять содержимое модели каждые 24 часа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

(Пишу в django 2.1)
У меня есть модель - visit_model. Как сделать так, чтобы она очищалась каждые 24 часа, и при этом мне не нужно было бы заходить на страницу, короче, чтобы очистка была в фоновом режиме?

Comment: Написать [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) и запускать её [кроном](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).